# While Loop echos only 1 value twice

Tags: php

I have a 2 tables called forums and forum_categories in database

> forum_categories
>   cat_id
>
> forums
>   cat_id

I am trying to count the total for each category for some reason it displays total record for all records.

> I have 2 categories so far in the database

**first category has value of 1**

**second category has value of 2**

In category one, I have two forums that has a cat_id of 1
In category two, I have one forum that has a cat_id of 2

it displays

> category 1 -------------------- 3 ---------------
>   category 2 -------------------- 3 ---------------

when it should display

> category 1 -------------------- 2 ---------------
>   category 2 -------------------- 1 ---------------
>
> $topics_count always displays 3.

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM forum_categories, forums WHERE forum_categories.cat_id = forums.cat_id GROUP BY forum_categories.cat_id";
$result = query($sql);



$sql2 = "SELECT fc.cat_title COUNT(f.forum_id) FROM forums as f LEFT JOIN forum_categories fc ON (f.cat_id = fc.cat_id) GROUP BY f.cat_id";
$result2 = query($sql2);
$topics_count = count($result2);



while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
    $forum_name = $row['forum_name']; 


    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>$cat_id</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='viewforum.php?f={$cat_id}'>$cat_title</a><br>$forum_name admin</td>";
    echo "<td>$topics_count</td>";
    echo "<td>0</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the table data?

Comment: I don't believe you should be getting 6 records from your query.  There should be only 3.

Comment: This is a PHP problem.  You are just printing the result set twice.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen don't understand how I can print the same result 2 times in different categories

Comment: Try your query in PHPMyAdmin and see what the result is

Comment: Mojtaba I have did that I have tried 90 different posts been at it for 2 days now same result if a cat_id is 2 and results are WHERE cat_id =cat_id it should never return values that don't equal it pulls all info correctly except the count

Comment: Well, `SELECT * FROM forums WHERE cat_id = cat_id` will select every record in your `forums` table; since `cat_id = cat_id` will always match and therefore is as good as not being there.

Comment: @ash I have removed it with same result I have tried over 60 sum odd posts on here not works how am I suppose to count how many records are in a category with no value to compare

Comment: @William let me know if anything still confuses you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

replace this

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {
```

with this

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Answer (score 3):

This bit of code below gives you all results:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM forums WHERE cat_id = cat_id";
$result2 = query($sql2);
$topics_count = row_count($result2); // here this would be 3*
```

*in case of 2 for cat1 + 1 for cat2 and you echo this in each table row as:

```
echo "<td>$topics_count</td>";
```

therefore you see the total number (3) on both rows.

What you are actually trying is to *join* `forums` and `forum_categories` table, get the `forum_categories.cat_title` and `COUNT(forums.cat_id)` while grouping the results by `forums.cat_id`

```
SELECT
    fc.cat_title,
    COUNT(f.forum_id)
FROM forums as f
LEFT JOIN forum_categories fc ON (f.cat_id = fc.cat_id)
GROUP BY f.cat_id
```

Here is the same demo [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/927f5/1) I've sent you yesterday.

Your query would then return you something like:

```
Demo Forum 1 | 2
Demo Forum 2 | 1
```

UPDATE:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT
            fc.cat_id,
            fc.cat_title,
            f.forum_name,
            COUNT(f.forum_id) as count
        FROM forums as f
        LEFT JOIN forum_categories fc ON (f.cat_id = fc.cat_id)
        GROUP BY f.cat_id";

$result2 = query($sql2);

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

    $cat_id = $row['cat_id']; // category id
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title']; // category title
    $forum_name = $row['forum_name']; // forum name
    $count = $row['count']; // count of forum_id (grouped by cat_id)

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$cat_id</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='viewforum.php?f={$cat_id}'>$cat_title</a><br>$forum_name admin</td>";
    echo "<td>$count</td>";
    echo "<td>0</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Here, I'm pretty sure the count would be okay, but not sure about "Forum Name".

Comment: Pretty much same as my query except, you have a working example with SQLFiddle +1

Comment: Right @ash, I've tried to explain it yesterday to him, and had the urge to still post this answer in case he can understand better now.  Otherwise, yours is already solving it as well.

Comment: @ash just to show I am not crazy I updated my code and the results changed from 3 in all categories to 1 in all categories

Comment: I use your code I get You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(f.forum_id) FROM forums as f LEFT JOIN forum_categories fc ON (f.cat_id = ' at line 1

Comment: @William oh sorry I forgot the comma before count, updated

Comment: @ Ekn still same result

Comment: There is no syntax error after adding the comma. Can you retry making sure it is just like the demo or code above and paste me your *latest sql* as a new section at the bottom of your question?

Comment: Wait... you should modify the table echo bit to get proper results printed I think cause the latest sql should work okay... on mobile now, can help on that in 5mins if you can't solve.

Comment: @Ekn Notice: Undefined index: count in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\cms\forums\index.php on line 50     line 50 is  $count = $row['count']; // count of forum_id (grouped by cat_id)

Comment: `$count = $row['count'];` would only work if you have `COUNT(f.forum_id) as count` on the SELECT bit. Also I hope you're not adding the //... bits really, those are comments. Updating answer

Comment: I appreciate the help I'm tired I'm just going to scrap it I have rewrote this little 20 lines of code a million times using a million ways and its just not working :-(

Comment: ... I really think you are very close though.

Comment: @Ekn this is to frustrating I can create a registration system in a matter of hours but I cant count rows in 2 days

Comment: @William I suggest taking a short break, clearing your head and returning back to debug it then. If you add your latest code and results as a new section in description I can still try to be helpful for a while more.